# use of qjson library

Tags: json, qt, qt-creator, qjson

When I try to use QJson library application cannot even start. I get message path\app.exe exited with code 128.
I include QJson in app.pro as follows`LIBS += qjson/lib/qjson0.dll`
QJson is in my project directory and I includ eserializer.h `#include "qjson/src/serializer.h"`
Then when I try to declare Serializer object`QJson::Serializer serializer;`I got this code 128 error when trying to run application. I tried to debug it and check on what line it has problems but it seems like it doesn't even start to execute main function, although the process mingw32-make.exe exited normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the qjson DLL is not found. Try adding the directory it is located in to the PATH, or copy the DLL into the same directory where your executable is.

Comment: Indeed it seems the DLL not found was reason of this problem. To solve this problem it was enough to change LIBS += qjson/lib/qjson0.dll into LIBS += "qjson/lib/qjson0.dll", i.e. adding quotation marks.

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure you didn't touch the path in between? LIBS only affects finding the lib at build-time (linking), not runtime.

Comment: Embarrassing mistake... I realized now that I've copied the dll file to project directory... So you're right that quotation marks don't matter.